# How come my text wont change in roblox studio when i update it with a code?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

So im trying to make a game about clicking cookies with Luau(roblox's version of lua) and the text property will change, but the new text will not actually show in game. Heres my script:

```
local clicks = 0

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    clicks = clicks + 1
    game.StarterGui.ScreenGui.e.Text = clicks
    print(clicks)
end)
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just to make sure, are numbers as Text allowed? And how do you know its not working, does the default value stay?

Comment: Yes thank you for helping i fixed my problem, the problem was i was not changing the text clientside

Answer (score 1):

Why it doesn't change is beacause you are using the wrong service,
you should be using:

```
local clicks = 0

script.Parent.Mouse.Button1Click:Connect(function()
    click = clicks + 1
    game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.e.Text = clicks
    print(clicks)
end)
```